# SQL generate a row automatically on table2, when a row is inserted to table1

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, table-relationships

I have the next table structure:

```
Users:

columns: user_id, ...


Users_Skins:

columns: user_id, ...
```

I want that if a users registers (`Users` is being populated), it will automatically add a row on Users_Skins with the `user_id` of the `Auto Increment`, to `Users_Skins`.

Should I search for the max `user_id`, and then insert a new row, or there is a better way (probably) ?

**EDIT:** I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Depends on your architecture. Triggers, code, managed classes, a service to do that. Does it have to be transparent for the application? I mean, come on, you are "a cook, I need good food, can you tell me what to do", instead of at least telling us what your requirements are.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to insert any additional data to User_Skins the trigger may be useful, something along those lines:

```
create trigger UsersInsert
on Users after insert as
begin
   insert into Users_Skins(user_id, ...)
   select i.user_id from inserted I         
end
```

Instead of trying to find maximum user_id and increment it I would rather use IDENTITY.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. On `Users_Skins` I only use a default value for 2 other fields. Thank you very much.